# How would humans react in a post- apocalipic world if they all became sick from a new virus?

Tags: post-apocalypse, viruses

I am working on writing a story where humans try to survive in a deserted wasteland where a highly contageous and mortal disease is spreading like wildfire. How would humans act or react to the situation?
Note: medicine can still be found in pharmacies, but it is hard to find stores that have not been ransacked.

Comment: `a deserted wasteland` and `be found in pharmacies`. Could you clarify please? If it's wasteland, how come pharmacies exist?

Comment: @adrian-colomitchi "but it is hard to find stores that have not been ransacked." that explain it?

Comment: @Topcode still unclear. How long ago the apocalypse has hit? If immediate, the 'wasteland' is not yet a complete wasteland but transitioning to there. If after some time, pharmacies or anything else from the past won't matter (unless somehow there are special circumstances the story author wants them to matter - but then it wouldn't be WB but story building)